# I want to select an item from an unordered list

Tags: jquery

I need to add a class to the list item that matches document.title.

My understanding is that I need to do something along the lines of

```
$('.mylist li:contains(thetitle)').addClass('blah')
```

but contains seems to take a string rather than a variable.  I am sure this is obvious, but I have wasted a stupid amount of time on it already. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this `$('.mylist li:contains(' + document.title + ')').addClass('blah')`?

Comment: Duh - my attempt at that had a typo I never discovered.  I gave you the answer because you had fewer points than krock and were almost as quick.  Thanks to both you.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the document.title to using standard string concatenation:

```
$('.mylist li:contains(' + document.title + ')').addClass('blah');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to quote the variable, since `contains` requires a string as a parameter. Additionally, if the `document.title` can contain quotes itself, you'll have to escape them.

```
var escaped = document.title.replace('\'', '\\\'');
$('.mylist li:contains(\'' + escaped + '\')').addClass('blah');
```